# How can I capture raw IP packets under Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, network-programming

I want to use Python to capture all the IP packets on an Ubuntu’s network. By using the below code, I’ve got all the packet with the Ethernet header. How can I get rid of the Ethernet header and directly get only the IP packets?

```
s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(0x0003))
while True:
    packet = s.recvfrom(65565)
```

Comment: The [Ethernet frame format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame) is well known and you can easily get the payload (which is the IP packet) if you have the [Ethernet frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame).

Comment: Thanks. But I mean is there a way to get raw IP packets directly, rather than  having other process after getting the Ethernet packets？

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you have a look at `scapy`, a tool that enables the user to send, sniff, dissect and forge network packets. the [sniffing](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sniffing) paragraph is a probably what you're looking for. Here's an example where I capture 10 IP packets, show a summary of their information, then store them to a pcap file:

```
$ scapy
Welcome to Scapy (2.3.2)
>>> pkts = sniff(filter='ip', count=10)
>>> print len(pkts)
10
>>> pkts.nsummary()
0000 Ether / IP / TCP 31.13.90.2:https > 192.168.1.14:63748 PA / Raw
0001 Ether / IP / TCP 192.168.1.14:63748 > 31.13.90.2:https A
0002 Ether / IP / TCP 192.168.1.14:63748 > 31.13.90.2:https PA / Raw
0003 Ether / IP / TCP 31.13.90.2:https > 192.168.1.14:63748 PA / Raw
0004 Ether / IP / TCP 192.168.1.14:63748 > 31.13.90.2:https A
0005 Ether / IP / UDP 192.168.1.21:48007 > 192.168.1.255:32412 / Raw
0006 Ether / IP / UDP 192.168.1.21:49808 > 192.168.1.255:32414 / Raw
0007 Ether / IP / UDP 192.168.1.11:64817 > 192.168.1.255:32412 / Raw
0008 Ether / IP / UDP 192.168.1.11:64819 > 192.168.1.255:32414 / Raw
0009 Ether / IP / UDP 192.168.1.11:49670 > 239.255.255.250:ssdp / Raw
>>> wrpcap("temp.cap",pkts)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)` will get you an IP Layer raw socket

`socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons (ETH_P_ALL))` will get you a layer 2 raw socket`

There are examples (in C) [here](http://www.pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html).

Comment: It doesn't work on my end. Perhaps it works only for C?

Comment: Raw sockets are provided by the OS regarding of language. Both C should be making the exact same system calls. Are you executing the application with elevated permissions?

Comment: I am using same line in my program: s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(0x0003)) and getting error that .. _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted .. what should I use instead of these parameters?

Comment: @ManishKumar you need root permissions to open a raw socket.

Comment: @Malt how I can do that if I am using Django framework?